# Problem with how Google indexes multi-language and multi-domain website

Tags: sitemap, google-index, multilingual

I have a problem with how Google indexes multilanguage/multidomain website.

Website itself handles two regions/languages and two domains. Language is identified by url param, not by the domain. Ideally we would want the website open either as **website.com/en** or **website.de/de**.

However that is not how Google indexes the site as I can see for example **website.de/en** or **website.com/de** in the results (depending how search is done). This is very confusing for the clients as it leads to the wrong version of the site.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to tell google to only index links for one site as **website.com/en/*** and the other as **website.de/de/*** and do not create a mix of both, like it does currently.

My initial though was to tweak the sitemap. At the moment it shows all the links existing on both en and de website, but with the .com domain. It looks like this

```
website.com/en
website.com/de
website.com/en/contact
website.com/de/kontakt
website.com/en/our-team
website.com/de/unser-team
```

and so on.

My question is. How can this problem be solved? Is a sitemap the best way to go? And if so, how should actually such sitemap look AD 2020 to handle this setup?

Or is there other solution?

Comment: Don't understand from your post: do you in fact have one site (.com), or two (.com and .de)?

Comment: One multisite (one instance), two domains, two languages (identified by url string - en and de)